# How much media queries?

Tags: css, media

How much media queries would you suggest to use?

I've made 4 designs:

960 for landscape-mode (ipad and more like Desktop)
768 for portrait-mode (ipad)
340 for portrait-mode (iphone)
and all above 960

Now my questions:

1) First I even don't know why I used 960 and not 1024. I read something a while ago, because of the scrollbar you've to reduce the width to 960. What about this regarding Tablets and Smartphones?

2) I've choosed these widths because I thought, if someone uses landscape mode, it would switch to the "ipad-media-query" and back to the "iphone-media-query". But that's just my theory. I'm new at media queries. That's why I ask. Appreciate any help or even your suggested CSS-code-examples to have the best amount of media queries covered for a website!?

3) I just want to cover most tablets, smartphones, desktops, etc. to be affected by the best media-query size. I would really appreciate your "best solutions"!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How long is a piece of string?

It's really up to you and your design as to how many media queries would be suitable to use and how you implement them.

As a guide I'd recommend looking at how Twitter Bootstrap implement their media queries. They've done a lot of research into it to arrive at their numbers so that would be a good starting point.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: What do you mean by your first question? Which string? Thank you for your link. I will look into that. But does this mean I've to install this bootstrap-framework or would you recommend that?

Comment: @Vay - It's just an expression, it means there isn't one definitive answer :-) I'm a big fan of Bootstrap so I'd recommend looking into it for use in your projects. For your current project if you've already done a lot of work it might not be worthwwhile.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm not so into English terms. :) Thanks, sounds very good. Well, I've got a little time pressure to finish this project, but sounds like it isn't that difficult to get into this.

Comment: How much wood would a woodchuck chuck it a woodchuck could chuck wood? At least 3.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to try to indentify breakpoints. The main reason for a breakpoint in an responsive website is to keep the experience optimal. You don't want to bring in a new media query for every new device or resolution.

Answer (score 2):

**Use as many media Queries as you need to.** You may shy away from using too many because you don't want a gigantic CSS file. But that wont significantly slow down the site. If you organize your media Queries well and use min and max widths for each query it will be very easy to keep track of your code.

**You can use one media Query for every orientation of every device if you want.** Of course ideally you want to use zero media queries and just make a perfect site that morphs perfectly. But that's not going to happen unless your site is super simple.

I use 9 media queries.

If you can widen the resolution parameters and get rid of a few media queries, all the better.

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries for:
240 x 320 (mobile), 
320 x 480 (mobile), 
480 x 640 (small tablet), 
768 x 1024 (tablet - portrait), 
1024 x 768 (tablet - landscape)

Considering width below 320px is a very good practice but for those who focus a lot about each and every visitor.

Answer (score 0):

i would use a dynamic layout which does not need media queries.

just use the media queries to hide/move elements.

you can use any number of them. just put some javascript in your page which displays your current browser width and then resize your browser to test when to hide elements. works for me

Comment: You mean using percentage-amounts to set the contents? Yes, but I don't want to have too much media-queries and also thought it would be better to avoid using JS.

Comment: yes, try as much as possible with that, then start hiding things with media queries. the javascript i mentioned is just for debugging, so you see how wide your browser currently is, while resizing

Answer (score 0):

The latest design world wants responsive design.

See this examples & use all media queries you want: http://nmsdvid.com/snippets/

Comment: Thank you. I know this page and that's also why I'm so confused, because there are so many sizes.

Comment: @Vay Go for only iphone, ipad & tab

Comment: Because most ppl use apple devices?